# How would I add live video streaming code to the graphite dashboard?

Tags: apache2, live-streaming, graphite, grafana, graphite-carbon

I am running an apache2 graphite host from an Orange Pi One, having written a service to translate and send data from sensors on the GPIO to the carbon line receiver. My project is to incorporate all the I/O from the device into a dashboard.

There are loads of graphite dashboards, but I can't find one that has a simple video stream applet/plugin.

I have searched graphite-web github and can easily adapt dashboard.html, but I am not sure whether the entire file is a placeholder, and whether any additions would render properly after all the javascript has run and rendered the page. It would seem I might need to reverse engineer the javascript, which seems quite an effort for the simple task I want.

If I can figure out the video stream code for the CSI camera, then I can adapt it to modify the dashboard with all the other data I want to display.

So, I am really looking for some guidance on getting started with dashboard code modification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the text panel to add HTML content to the dashboard.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please? Which dashboard? I don't see anywhere to add a "text panel" to the standard graphite dashboard. Do you mean i need to use a grafana dashboard with a text panel?

Comment: @CharlieS "Do you mean i need to use a grafana dashboard with a text panel?" I am pretty sure this is what he means

Comment: Yes, I'm not aware of a way to do it in graphite-web.  Grafana will give you a lot more flexibility for building dashboards, including the ability to add panels witb html in them.